# Getting correct html form action attribute with JSF + Spring 3

Tags: spring, jsf

I am trying to mix Spring MVC with Java Server Faces. I have a Spring 3.2 `@Controller` class, which returns a `ModelAndView` that is resolved to a JSF view. That view contains a `<h:form>` tag. The problem that I am having is that, on the rendered HTML, the form `action` attribute combines the original request URL with the name to resolve the view, creating a strange meaningless URL to which the form is POSTed. What I want is just the view name, without the original request URL.

Here is my controller class (`org.my.test.MainController`):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class MainController
{
  @RequestMapping(value="/{itemId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView retrieveItem( @PathVariable long itemId ) {

    /* Retrieve item */

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject ("itemName", "A retrieved item");
    mav.addObject ("itemId", itemId);
    mav.setViewName ("/items");
    return mav;
  }
}
```

Here is my JSF template (`/items.xhtml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Edit item</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h3>Edit item</h3>
        <p>
            Item name: <h:inputText name="itemName" value="#{itemName}" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Item id: <h:inputText name="itemId" value="#{itemId}" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

When I request the page `http://localhost:8081/items/12345`, what is served is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Edit item</title></head><body><form id="j_id_6" name="j_id_6" method="post" action="/items/12345/items.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <h3>Edit item</h3>
        <p>
            Item name: <input id="j_id_6:j_id_8" name="j_id_6:j_id_8" type="text" value="A retrieved item" />
        </p>
        <p>
            Item id: <input id="j_id_6:j_id_a" name="j_id_6:j_id_a" type="text" value="12345" />
        </p>
        <p><input id="j_id_6:j_id_c" name="j_id_6:j_id_c" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p><input type="hidden" name="j_id_6_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="oyc7wGGKZrPGinPPmrv9PmTDy0GBlI3c+pjWpdK0KuY69faJ" /></form></body>
</html>
```

My problem is the bit that says `action="/items/12345/items.xhtml"` What I want is `action="/items"` or `action="/items.xhtml"`

My question has two parts: why is my setup combining the request URL with the view ID like this, and how do I make it stop?

Here is `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Minimal JSF + Spring test</display-name>

    <!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller 
        implementations). -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/ui-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize, *not* used at runtime -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Just here so the JSF implementation can initialize -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is Spring config `ui-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.my.test" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="faceletsViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is main Spring config `application-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.my.test" />
</beans>
```

And here is `faces-config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

This is all running in embedded Jetty 9.0.4. I have tried two different JSF implementations, Apache My-Faces 2.1.11 and Mojarra 2.2.1, both with the same effect. Spring version is 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `url-mapping` in `web.xml` from "/" to "/*" corrected the problem.

Everything is in fact behaving according to the Servlet spec (Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0 Rev a, Section 12.2, page 116):

- A string beginning with a `/` character and ending with a `/*` suffix is used for path mapping.

  ...
- A string containing only the `/` character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.

(Thank you to this post on Coderanch: http://www.coderanch.com/t/366340/Servlets/java/servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

(Java Servlet 3.0 spec available at http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/)